# Is it possible to remove '&nbsp' using JQuery..?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two buttons in a row and they are shown in two td's, and its not lined up correctly in IE, I doubt that hidden spaces(&nbsp) in the td's somewhere mayby after the input or before the input button,  unfortunately I cant access the html code, its automatically generated. The only way is to control by using jQuery I have a jQuery something like this..

```
$("td:contains('&nbsp;')").css("display", "none");
```

Is this a right way to get rid of that &nbsp in the td?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, you would do something along these lines:

```
$("td").html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
});
```

Comment: minitech, thanks for the quick response by the way what is that 'g' stands for in this line..? 'replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));'

Comment: @AkhilPaul: It stands for "global". Without the global flag, only one replacement maximum will be done, rather than all of them.

Comment: @AkhilPaul: You forgot to add jQuery to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/FLwaB/2/ :)

Comment: The only downside to this approach is that any constructs tied to the old html (such as data and event handlers) will be removed! To avoid that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825542/422845).

Answer (score 4):

Rather than answering the OP's specific scenario, if we take the question title ("Is it possible to remove '&nbsp' using JQuery..?") and answer this in a general way (which I think is useful), then any answers using `.html()` have one fundamental flaw: replacing the html this way also removes any data and event handlers associated with the old html - not desirable! It may work for the OP's specific scenario, but I think it's useful to answer the question in a more general way...

The better way is to replace the `.textContent` of individual text nodes within the element. So given the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    &nbsp;<a href="www.google.com">Here is a link &nbsp;</a>
    <p>Here is a paragraph with another link inside: <a href="www.facebook.com">&nbsp;&nbsp;another link&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;</p>
    And some final text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

We can remove all `&nbsp;` (which is unicode `\u00A0` - see more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27028621/422845)) like so:

```
$('.container, .container *').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) { // text node
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/\u00A0/g, '');
    }
});
```

`$('.container, .container *')` selects the container and all elements inside it, then [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) selects all the children of those elements, including text nodes. We go through each of those nodes, and for every text node we encounter (`nodeType === 3`), we replace the `&nbsp;` (`\u00A0`) with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

NBSP is not an element, so you can't hide it.

What you could do is to rewrite the element which contains NBSP... like this:

```
 $('#container').html( $('#container').html().split('&nbsp').join('') );
```

Also detecting where NBSP using jquery.contains and setting it's parent element a class with font size 0 or display none could do the trick.

Note than if you choose to rewrite the HTML to erase unwanted NBSP all events previously attached will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var td = $("td:contains('&nbsp;')");
var html = td.html();
html = html.replace("&nbsp;","");
td.html(html);
```

Comment: That assumes that there's only one element with items to replace, and the question states that there are two.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this, at the end the solution was quite obvious, instead of using `.html()` had to use `.text()`

Example:

```
var text = $(label).text();
    text.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#div').text($('#div').text().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' '));
```