# JQuery how to remove all <br> and '&nbsp;' before the first <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is

```
<br />
&nbsp; 
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>qqqqq</p>
<br />
<p>222</p>
```

and the JS is

```
$('p:first').prevAll('br').remove();
```

how to remove all the `&nbsp;`

Comment: My doubt is that why this question is not up or DOWn voted.

Comment: Where's jQM, CSS, Ajax relevant code? dont use irrelevant tags pls.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the first `p` tag, then use `prevAll` to get the `br` elements to remove:

```
$('p:first').prevAll('br').remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyh7B/)

Comment: And if i want to remove all 'br' and delete all '&nbsp;' before the first 'p',how to do?

Comment: See here for how to remove non breaking spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589528/is-it-possible-to-remove-nbsp-using-jquery

Comment: I don't know how to get all '&nbsp;' before the first <p>

Comment: @user3339775 you're probably best to start a new question about &nbsp; removal.

Comment: I can only post once every 90 minutes.Please help me in this question

Answer (score 3):

You can use [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to get element before the target element. To get the first `p` you can use `p:first` selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz7p8/1/)**

```
$('p:first').prevAll('br').remove();
```

[.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

> Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: And if i want to remove all 'br' and delete all '&nbsp;' before the first 'p',how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.prevUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/prevuntil/) too :

```
$('p:first').prevUntil().remove();
```

Example :  http://jsfiddle.net/yB5WH/

Comment: And if i want to remove all 'br' and delete all '&nbsp;' before the first 'p',how to do?

Comment: update your question or open a new thread to show your HTML containing `&nbsp;`