# Replace nbsp; with <br/>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to include this kind of code to a second place.

```
<div id="social-links">
  <!-- Facebook -->
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/name" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i>
    Facebook
  </a>
  &nbsp;

  <!-- Google+ -->
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/+name" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i>
    Google+
  </a>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Because of the available width I want to replace the `&nbsp;` with `<br/>`.

This is my current code but it doesn't work:

```
$( "&nbsp;" ).replaceWith( "<br/>" );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrv8e3j/)

Comment: Why not using a decent text editor?

Comment: How do you know which one hes using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here you go:

```
$('#social-links').html($('#social-links').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,"<br/>"));
```

**UPDATE:**

Now that I think about it again after 3 years, I'd do it this way:

```
const $socialLinks = $('#social-links');
$socialLinks.html($socialLinks.html().split('&nbsp;').join('<br/>'));
```

It has much better performance than the previous code.

Answer (score 2):

If you like plain JS:

```
var socialLink = document.getElementbyId("social-links");
socialLink.innerHTML = socialLink.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"<br/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#social-links').html($('#social-links').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '<br/>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah man, late to the party!

Fixed here in a slightly longer version:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '<br/>'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/jyrv8e3j/2/

This question has been asked before by the way: [Is it possible to remove '&nbsp' using JQuery..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589528/is-it-possible-to-remove-nbsp-using-jquery)

Try a thorough search before asking next time