# &nbsp; being generated in P tags by browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been building a [wordpress site](http://nanosteamdrying.boostmktg.webfactional.com/) from a theme for a little while now and noticed that in certain instances in the `p` tags `&nbsp;` characters are being generated by either the browser or the CSS. Don't really know which one though, but it's getting annoying since it's messing up the type.

I recently added

```
.entry-content {
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    -ms-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

to prevent hyphenation from happening, but I think this might be related to the updated CSS or the "Visual Composer" editor that I'm forced to use with this theme.I've already confirmed that I don't have `&nbsp;` in the [editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KghX.jpg) which I hoped would be the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll find those are being generated by WordPress, not the browser.

Comment: But it just the space between words, what's wrong with that?

Comment: WYSIWYG editors add one whitespace HTML character whenever two spaces are added between words or sentences because HTML spec reduces empty whitespace to one character. That may be what's happening.

Comment: The code from the WYSIWYG editor is `<p>New uses are being constantly discovered in different industries. Recent applications include drying automotive parts, packaging  and battery materials.</p>` It doesn't have `&nbsp;` in it. You can see in the source code they're also not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This non-`&nbsp;` character is actually `&#160;`, which Chrome and Safari will render as `&nbsp;`, but display as `" "` from within the inspector edit feature, the source code, and the WYSIWYG editor.

The full explanation is [from Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962323/what-is-this-insane-space-character-google-chrome) where he goes through the HEX code. Going back through the code and simply retyping everything to use the traditional space fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `&nbsp;` entities are space characters, not hyphens. Secondly, the CSS is not generating those, it is WordPress that generates extra markup. This may be a result of the WYSIWYG editor, or the theme itself, but it is impossible to know based on your question.

You can use the following code to prevent WordPress from creating extra markup:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

But, the problem is also likely with a related plugin. Try disabling all plugins and see if the problem still arises.

Comment: The code from the WYSIWYG editor is `<p>New uses are being constantly discovered in different industries. Recent applications include drying automotive parts, packaging and battery materials.</p>` It doesn't have `&nbsp;` in it and it doesn't display in the source code. `hyphens: auto` was originally turned on so I don't see how WP is generating it in post.

Comment: Sorry, a bit confusing, here's more on the hyphens: The hyphens were originally turned on in the theme css by default. I had disabled those and noticed this issue occurring. Potentially it's wholly unrelated to the hyphens and the issue was already occurring, just unnoticed because of the hyphens breaks. Deactivating all of the plugins of the wordpress removes the formatting of the page but also still displays this text with `&nbsp;` in the inspector.