# Search email via Restrict where subject includes non-ascii characters (unicode #160)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to search for emails, by subject, in a folder and reply to them via Excel VBA.

I use Restrict via DASL query. I search for emails by the exact string I know they will have.

My idea was to iterate through a range in a sheet that will have the exact mail subject (built using a formula) and the string to reply with.

The code finds a match if I copy paste the subject from Outlook but not when I use the subject built from my formula.

Further testing led me to find a couple of non-ascii characters (unicode #160). How can I add % between each filter to ignore " " between words and not have to deal with non-ascii characters?
I suppose I could modify my formula to include them but I can't ascertain there won't be other non-ascii characters there.

```vb
Sub RespondTassks()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olFldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim replyall As Outlook.MailItem
Dim emailItems As Outlook.items
Dim Filter As String
Dim subject As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFldr = Fldr.Folders("SchedulingCA")

subject1 = "[Task/SCH] Validacion Final Cancelacion orden 612666 del DF6548100  - ID#1935"
subject2 = "[Task/SCH] Validacion Final Cancelacion orden 612666 del DF6548100  - ID#1935"

Filter1 = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                    Chr(34) & "Like '%" & subject1 & "%'"

Filter2 = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                    Chr(34) & " Like '%" & subject2 & "%'"

Set emailItems = olFldr.items.Restrict(Filter1)
    
If emailItems.Count = 0 Then
    'RespondTasks = "No task mail found."
    Exit Sub
Else
    If emailItems.Count > 1 Then
        'RespondTasks = "Multiple task mails found"
    End If
End If

For i = emailItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    DoEvents
    
    If TypeOf emailItems(i) Is MailItem Then
        Set olMail = emailItems(i)
        Debug.Print olMail.subject & " " & olMail.ReceivedTime
        
        Set replyall = olMail.replyall
        
        With replyall
            .HTMLBody = replyText
            .Display
        End With
        
        'RespondTasks = "Reply sent"
        
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I need to deal with one email per subject, if there are more than one I need to give the user a message that there were multiple matches found.

Comment: May the bigger question is why the data coming from Excel is different? Where do these non-ASCII characters get lost or replaced? You mighr also want to us ci_phrasematch operator instead of like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-for-a-phrase-in-the-body-of-items-in-a-folder

Comment: Like I said, the data coming from Excel comes from a formula I built using the same parameters the emails' subject will have. At simple view, my formula builds the subject exactly as the email subject - what I didn't forsee are non-ASCII characters coming from the subject.

Comment: Do try ci_phrasematch operator...

Comment: I will. I am still curious tho, I tried using wildcards between words “%” with Restrict but they didnt work. Do wildcards only work if they are at the end and beginning of the filter? What other way of searching can I use to search with wild cards and that will return email items with their meta data (receive date, etc) accesible?

Comment: Yes, MAPI only allows prefix or substring search, so it can only be "%string" or "%string%"

Answer (score 1):

Replace any non-breaking space with a normal space.

```
Private Sub replace_nbsp()

    Dim strIn As String
    Dim Result As String
    
    strIn = "a" & Chr(160) & "b"
    Debug.Print "strIn.:" & strIn
        
    ' replace nbsp with space
    Result = Replace(strIn, Chr(160), " ")
    
    Debug.Print "Result:" & Result

End Sub
```

[What is this INSANE space character??? (google chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962323/what-is-this-insane-space-character-google-chrome)