# JQuery Mobile tabs are not aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm currently building a cordova app and on my android phone screen the tabs look like this:

[image: Tabs]
The above picture was run in JSFiddle with JQuery 2.1.0 and the JQM 1.4.2 option checked off with the code:

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link by request:
https://jsfiddle.net/simonshout/18sssw7m/

My android code has a lot more HTML wrapped in and around this module but it kinda worked out where both my android phone and jsfiddle are rendering this the wrong way. So what am I missing?

Also after some testing around I saw that a bunch of "nbsp" are being injected between each li class. I don't know what's causing that but how would I stop it?

Comment: Can you please post your JSFiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/simonshout/18sssw7m/

Answer (score 1):

Alright sorry to be that guy but i did do a little more digging and I found a duplicate thread(s):

[How do I remove invisible "&nbsp;&nbsp;" which has been automatically added to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110467/how-do-i-remove-invisible-nbspnbsp-which-has-been-automatically-added-to-c)

[is there a way to highlight all the special accent characters in sublime text or any other text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976022/is-there-a-way-to-highlight-all-the-special-accent-characters-in-sublime-text-or)

Answer (score 0):

You need your navbar inside the `data-role="tabs"`.

Here's your [modified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18sssw7m/1/)