# JQuery Mobile : navbar inside footer last element displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, sublimetext, sublimetext3, jquery-mobile-navbar

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.4.5, and I have no custom CSS of any kind.
Code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-id">
    ...
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="overflow:hidden;" data-hide-during-focus="false">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">Navbar 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Navbar 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Navbar 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Navbar 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Navbar 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

The last element in the navbar list is displaying on the next line, as if text wrapped.

[image]

I cannot figure out what is causing the last element to be misaligned like that.

I have tried this in various different  elements on the page, as well as with 2, 3, 4, and 5 elements in the list. The behavior is the same, regardless of browser (Safari or Chrome).

Can anyone help?

Comment: I tried the given code in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and it looks good. Maybe it's related to surrounding HTML? Here your code as [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzofauya/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not caused by JQuery Mobile, but actually by the text editor (in this case Sublime Text 3) displaying a regular space character and a UNICODE space character the same way.

The UNICODE spaces--which were left over from a copy-paste from a source document--are converted by the browser into `&nbsp;`'s, which then cause the line-wrapping issue. 
[image]

Replacing the UNICODE spaces with space-bar spaces in the HTML fixed the issue.
[image]

For Sublime Text users, to avoid this in the future install the [Unicode Character Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Unicode%20Character%20Highlighter) package.

Comment: This is a duplicate question and answer, but the others were titled in such a way that they did not show up in my searches. Links in the following comments.

Comment: [jquery mobile tabs are not aligned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444020/jquery-mobile-tabs-are-not-aligned)

Comment: [How do I remove invisible “&nbsp;&nbsp;” which has been automatically added to code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110467/how-do-i-remove-invisible-nbspnbsp-which-has-been-automatically-added-to-c)