# How to remove blank space when hit enter in tinymce

Tags: jquery

I have a form with tinymce Editor with jquery validation . My problem is when i enter space and press submit button ,it does not show required field message because it returns the content as follows

```
`<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`
```

I found  HTMLPurifier  as a solution but i need to know is there any function in tinymce itself to remove blank space before form submission.

Comment: See http://formvalidation.io/examples/tinymce/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove '&nbsp' using JQuery..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589528/is-it-possible-to-remove-nbsp-using-jquery)